# schedule conflict flutter firebase in adding a date that has already been taken

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to achieve schedule conflict in my uni app, itenerary, where  a user wouldnt be allowed to add a trip that has a date that is already taken.

I am struggling to get the right query but this is what i have tried

```
List dateinput= [];

DateTime? pickeddate = await showDatePicker(context: context,
                      initialDate:DateTime.now(),
                     firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 0)),
                     lastDate: DateTime(2025));
                     setState(() {
                       date.text= DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickeddate!);
                                });

//my query 
final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserTrip')                                   
                                    .orderBy('tripDate')
                                    .get()
                                    .then((value) =>
                                        value.docs.forEach((element) {
                                          List data1 = element.data() as List;
                                          dateinput.add(data1);
                                          print(dateinput);
                                        }));

//and I'm trying to implement that return error on pressed on the add trip button 
 if (dateinput.contains(date.text)) {
                                //return error
                              } else {
                                uploadFile();}
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh my apologies. thank you for this comment, I'll try to edit it

Comment: Thanks for that edit. What isn't working when you run this code? If you [set a breakpoint](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/debugging#setting-breakpoints) on each line of the code you shared, [run the code in the debugger](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/debugger), and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I am getting this in my debug console instead of the print /flutter ( 1665): #0      _AddTDState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:iteneraryproject/addTitleDate.dart:311
E/flutter ( 1665): #1      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:416:8)
E/flutter ( 1665): #2      _AddTDState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:iteneraryproject/addTitleDate.dart:310
E/flutter ( 1665): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this one too [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: Please provide this information in your question, instead of in comments - so that others are also more likely to see it. With that, you might also want to search for the error message you get, as this has come up a few times before.